# Corona SDK and starting app

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning Corona SDK and I have one problem: 
my applications starting twice with Corona Simulator. Is that right?
I'm creating main.lua with

```
print("test")
```

and getting in console something like

```
Windows simulator build date: Aug 27 2012 @ 17:37:09


Copyright (C) 2009-2012  C o r o n a   L a b s   I n c .
        Version: 2.0.0
        Build: 2012.894
test

Copyright (C) 2009-2012  C o r o n a   L a b s   I n c .
        Version: 2.0.0
        Build: 2012.894
test
```

Why so? It's problem, because my socket client on start connects to server two times.
What's wrong?

Upd: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with Lua plugin for starting project and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Corona Labs\Corona SDK\Corona Simulator.exe" as Lua interpreter

Comment: I noticed the same thing with my debugger (also socket-based) and would also like to know what may be causing this behavior. I do see the application being started twice (the second time after the first one is completed). What's interesting is that the UI window is only created during the second run, so from the user perspective everything looks okay, even though the code appears to be executed twice.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem because I had the simulator settings configured to restart when it detected file changes. One of my functions saved to an external file on startup (i.e. changed it) and so it restarted over and over.

Is there something in your code that could be writing to a file? 
Or is it literally just the one print function at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

This might fix it.make sure you are installing two Corona SDKs. Then uninstall it completely,and install it again.

Comment: I didn't quite get the answer. Are you trying to say make sure you *don't* install two SDKs? Or are you suggesting to install two and then remove one of them?

I'm quite sure that in my case I only have one installed and still have the same problem.

Comment: sometimes when you install the update(new corona build),it dose not remove the old one.you have to uninstall the old one yourself.look at your application to see if you have just one installed.then if you only have one(which you should)uninstall it and install it again.